# iOS - Editable Forms (Contact App style)

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I'm in the process of creating an iOS5 application, what I'm after is the 'Edit' button functionality, specifically, taking a dynamically populated plain style TableView, and when the Edit button in the NavBar is pressed, it changes the form into an editable (and grouped style) TableView.

This functionality is seen through most Apple applications where the user can edit stored data.  Can anyone tell me if there are specific calls that can be made to get this?  I thought there be an official approach or pattern to be used, seeing as it appears so frequently in Apple applications.

I've been searching the internet and haven't found anything conclusive as of yet.  Any suggestions welcome, or design patterns/approaches etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [UITableView class](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) reference. Particularly the section on "Managing the  Editing of Table Cells"

And also the Table View Programming guide section on [Editing Mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW19).

Comment: Thanks.  It's not as clear-cut as I thought it'd be, especially seeing as it's a recurring pattern in Apple apps, but good nonetheless. Thanks.